# Sudden strange behavior from old plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I created the plugin below to display a simple hierarchical list of posts (in this case job vacancies) some time ago.

It's recently it's begun displaying the title of the first item in the hierarchy incorrectly - taking the title of one of it sub categories. I'm unable to see why a wordpress update or something similar might cause this to happen?!

```html
<?php

class FSSVacancyWidget extends WP_Widget
{
  function FSSVacancyWidget()
  {
    $widget_ops = array('classname' => 'FSSVacancyWidget', 'description' => 'Displays Recent FSS Jobs on the homepage and all other pages' );
    $this->WP_Widget('FSSVacancyWidget', 'FSS Vacancies', $widget_ops);
  }
 
  function form($instance)
  {
    $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, array( 'title' => '' ) );
    $title = $instance['title'];
    $fss_numposts = $instance['fss_numposts'];
    $fss_vacurl = $instance['fss_vacurl'];
    $fss_morevac = $instance['fss_morevac'];
?>
 <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>">Title: <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo attribute_escape($title); ?>" /></label></p>
 <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('fss_numposts'); ?>">Number of Posts (Default is 10): <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('fss_numposts'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('fss_numposts'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo attribute_escape($fss_numposts); ?>" /></label></p>
 <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('fss_vacurl'); ?>">Vacancy URL: <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('fss_vacurl'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('fss_vacurl'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo attribute_escape($fss_vacurl); ?>" /></label></p> 
 <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('fss_morevac'); ?>">More Vacancies Title: <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('fss_morevac'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('fss_morevac'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo attribute_escape($fss_morevac); ?>" /></label></p> 
 
<?php
  }
 
  function update($new_instance, $old_instance)
  {
    $instance = $old_instance;
    $instance['title'] = $new_instance['title'];
    $instance['fss_numposts'] = $new_instance['fss_numposts'];
    $instance['fss_vacurl'] = $new_instance['fss_vacurl'];
    $instance['fss_morevac'] = $new_instance['fss_morevac'];
    return $instance;
  }
 
  function widget($args, $instance)
  {
    extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);
  
  /* User-selected settings. */
   $fss_numposts = $instance['fss_numposts'];
   $fss_vacurl = $instance['fss_vacurl'];
   $fss_morevac = $instance['fss_morevac'];
    
    echo $before_widget;
    $title = empty($instance['title']) ? ' ' : apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);
 
    if (!empty($title))
      echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;;
 
    // WIDGET CODE 
 echo "<ul class='items'>";
 
 query_posts( array( 'showposts' => $fss_numposts ) );
 if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
 echo "<li><a href='".get_permalink()."'><span class='job-title'>".get_the_title()."</span><span class='job-date'>".get_the_date('d m Y')."</span></a></li>";
 
 endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query();
 
 echo "</ul>";
 echo"<a href='".$fss_vacurl."' class='view'>".$fss_morevac."</a>";
 
 echo $after_widget;
  }
 
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("FSSVacancyWidget");') );
?>
```

Comment: i think this is not your code problem but this is your PHP displaying problem PHP code not running in your Snippet Tools . it just displayed all code from these area.

Answer (score 1):

Your widget is completely out of date and quite useless to try and debug and fix. This is unfortunately the truth.

Here are the big issues

- Support for php 5.3 was dropped last year, you are still supporting versions prior to this which leads to vulnerablities in security that can be easily exploited by hackers
- `create_function()` should not be used, this is pre php 5.3. This is a serious security loop hole in your code, very dangerous. Make use of proper closures (`function()`) which was introduced in php 5.3 and which is still supported
- `extract()` was completely removed from Wordpress core a year ago. (*CAVEAT: I think there is still one function left though, the core developers still need to find a replacement, just can't remember which one*). `extract()` is very inconsistent and do break variables inside an instance. You should avoid using it. Just the fact that it was removed from all functions in core, it should really tell you how bad it really is
- You must never ever use `query_posts`. It breaks the main query and very important functions like `get_queried_object()` and globals like `$post`  on which so many plugins and other features like recent posts depend on. It totally breaks pagination and in most cases outright fails, specially cases like infinite scroll. `query_posts` also slows page loads as it reruns queries. You should be using `WP_Query` instead in your widget
- Use the constructor method (`__construct`) instead of the class name as your main constructor. This is pre php5 syntax. As I already stated, php 5.3 was dropped last year, why are you still supporting versions pre version 5. I cannot emphasize this enough, support for such old versions leads to security vulnerability

The best advice I can give you to solve your issue is to check out the [Widget API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API)  and [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and then rewrite (actually writing a complete new widget) your widgt according to those guidelines